# java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.Application

Tags: android

I have got an error and just have a guess what does it mean. I have an app that works for a long and could be killed with entire process So my guess is that a part of code that was executed try to send some message to the part that didn't exist (frankly it exists but in another process because it was recreated)

Could you please tell me what does this error mean?

**UPDATE**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@42b3bcc0 (pid=28461) when publishing content providers
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.publishContentProviders(ActivityManagerNative.java:2325)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4021)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3963)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(28461): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post some of your code(any bit that you think might be causing the problem) and the logcat

Comment: Excuse me, but I shouldn't share this code. I extend my question and add stacktrace from remote device. I have got a lot exception followed one by one

Comment: If you don't want to share code, at least describe what you are trying to do. Also consider renaming classes, posting only a relevant part, maybe the manifest of the app?. etc.

Comment: Hello, Nikolay. My app get data from sensors, calculate accelereation vector and send it with current coordinates to the server. I have to Services: first for gathering data is started with START_STICKY as foreground, seond for communication with the server is started as NOT_STICKY and keeps wake_lock during his life. All communications from tasks in another threads and android compopent works trought ResultReceiver which I pass via intent to communication service and set it to the task. Even in foreground mode my service for sensors data could be killed but I handle this: I start sensors agai

Comment: It is difficult to say where I have got an exception like above but my guess is when my proccess is killed and recretaed again I have a small chance to have some task in background that complete his work and pass the result throught result receiver but this rs try to send data to the process that has been killed and it is get this SecurityException, I haven't know more about ApplicationThreadProxy in android so I just wnadering in the darkness

Comment: Its should be Open